# SQL Trigger is not working for Audit

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger, ora-00984

Requirement:
Once any update on column value in table `OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL`, we have to insert one row in `ACTIVITY_LABEL_AUDIT_LOG` table which is having columns as `TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, OLD_VALUE, NEW_VALUE, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DTM`

I have created Trigger as below. Trigger created with below compilation errors:

> ```
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
> ```

Please help me on this.

```
create or replace TRIGGER ACTIVITY_LABEL_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OF ACTIVITY_LABEL, NOTES
ON OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ACTIVITY_LABEL_AUDIT_LOG
   ( TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME,
     OLD_VALUE,
     NEW_VALUE,
     UPDATED_BY,
     UPDATED_DTM)   
     VALUES   

   ('OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL',
    'ACTIVITY_LABEL',
    OLD.ACTIVITY_LABEL,
    NEW.ACTIVITY_LABEL,
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
    NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DTM); 

END;
```

Comment: "`ACTIVITY_LABEL, NOTES`" What's `NOTES`?

Comment: NOTES is a  Column name but here I am checking for column ACTIVITY_LABEL first. once this is fixed  I wanted to check for notes column

Comment: Column names don't belong there. That's giving you the error. Remove it.

Comment: No, the column names are fine. It is the `NEW.xxx, use `NEW.xxx` instead

Comment: @wolφi: Yes you're right. I confused `OF` with `ON`...

Answer (score 0):

Just Prefix OLD and NEW with colons(`:`) as in the following ( *ORA-00984* raise because of this, by the way I assume there's no problem with column names ) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTIVITY_LABEL_TRIGGER
AFTER ON OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if ( nvl(:OLD.ACTIVITY_LABEL,'xYz#@!') != nvl(:NEW.ACTIVITY_LABEL,'xYz#@!')
   or nvl(:OLD.NOTES,'xYz#@!') != nvl(:NEW.NOTES,'xYz#@!') ) then
  INSERT INTO ACTIVITY_LABEL_AUDIT_LOG
    (TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME,
     OLD_VALUE,
     NEW_VALUE,
     UPDATED_BY,
     UPDATED_DTM)
  VALUES  
    ('OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL',
     'ACTIVITY_LABEL',
     :OLD.ACTIVITY_LABEL,
     :NEW.ACTIVITY_LABEL,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DTM);
 end if;
END;
```

With respect to your comment, I remove the part `UPDATE OF ACTIVITY_LABEL, NOTES` and make comparison for two columns `ACTIVITY_LABEL` and `NOTES` in the *IF statement*. If you want to get every log for each *update* operation, you should also remove the *IF statement*.

Comment: Thank you its working,  but now I wanted to insert one record for each column if it updated. Could you please guid me how to write the code.

Comment: If there is an update on two columns I have to insert tow rows in Audit table with table name, column name , old value and new value. I have to check for all the columns for which there is a possible to to update the column value and insert a row for each column in Audit table. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers, based on your answers finally I have achieved the requirement with the below code :

```
create or replace TRIGGER ACTIVITY_LABEL_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE OF ACTIVITY_LABEL, NOTES
ON OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if ( nvl(:OLD.ACTIVITY_LABEL,'xYz#@!') != nvl(:NEW.ACTIVITY_LABEL,'xYz#@!')) then
  INSERT INTO ACTIVITY_LABEL_AUDIT_LOG
    (TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME,
     OLD_VALUE,
     NEW_VALUE,
     UPDATED_BY,
     UPDATED_DTM)
  VALUES  
    ('OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL',
     'ACTIVITY_LABEL',
     :OLD.ACTIVITY_LABEL,
     :NEW.ACTIVITY_LABEL,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DTM);
 end if;

 if (nvl(:OLD.NOTES,'xYz#@!') != nvl(:NEW.NOTES,'xYz#@!') ) then
  INSERT INTO ACTIVITY_LABEL_AUDIT_LOG
    (TABLE_NAME,
     COLUMN_NAME,
     OLD_VALUE,
     NEW_VALUE,
     UPDATED_BY,
     UPDATED_DTM)
  VALUES  
    ('OPS_BUILD_ACTIVITY_LABEL',
     'NOTES',
     :OLD.NOTES,
     :NEW.NOTES,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
     :NEW.LAST_UPDATED_DTM);
 end if;
END;
```